# How to find all values in column A but not in column B in excel?

Tags: excel

find all data from A column which are not in B column ?

for example and both A and B columns are not sorted,

```
A        B
111    222
222    111
555
444

then I'd like to have 
555
444
in column C
```

i think there is a way to find this in excel, can someone remind me of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we perform common set operations (union, intersection, minus) in MS Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186547/how-can-we-perform-common-set-operations-union-intersection-minus-in-ms-exce)

Answer (score 0):

Please enter the formula below in C2 and copy down.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A2),"",A2)
```

Next, copy / Paste Special > Values to replace the formulas with values and then sort or filter to [re]move the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in A1 with no headers, you can place this array-formula in C1 and fill down:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$4,$B$1:$B$2,0)),ROW($A$1:$A$4)),ROW(1:1))),"")`

The array-formula needs to be saved to just C1 using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and then filled down after saving.

Adjust A1:A4 and B1:B2 ranges to include all of your data.

[image]