# Excel filter using the Dynamic Array of another filter function

Tags: arrays, excel, filter

I have been struggling with this for a while and am unable to find a solution on google, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

The function is trying to list all the courses that a student is taking, based on all the students that are taking "English".

I am trying to filter a table based on the output of another filter function. This function below works perfectly when the output of the second filter function is only 1 value, but as soon as it outputs a dynamic array of more than 1 value, an error occurs. Please let me know if there is an easier way to do this, or if I am doing something wrong.

Thank you.

=FILTER(Table1[[#All],[Course]],Table1[[#All],[Surname - Given Names]] = FILTER(Table1[[#All],[Surname - Given Names]],Table1[[#All],[Course]]="English"))

Comment: `FILTER()` function can't compare with many value. Post few sample data and desired output. There may any other formulas to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Harun24hr said, you cannot compare each individual element (given_names) in the dynamic array with multiple values. The filter function simply takes one final TRUE or FALSE for each row in the table while your written criteria give a list of TRUE or FALSE for each row which is why your external filter fails when you have multiple results of your inner filter.

You can use this formula instead:

```
=LET( table,             Table1[[#All],[Course]], 
      criteria_clmn,     Table1[[#All],[Surname - Given Names]], 
      filter_list,       FILTER(Table1[[#All],[Surname - Given Names]],Table1[[#All],[Course]]="English"),   
      criteria_result,   XLOOKUP(criteria_clmn, filter_list, filter_list = filter_list, FALSE),   
      filtered_table,    FILTER(table,  criteria_result,  NA()),
      filtered_table
    )
```

you can change/play with the first three parameters (table, criteria_clmn, and filter list)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for **Microsoft 365**

*Using [SCAN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67), [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67), [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929), [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759), Optional: [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)*

By using ***SCAN*** we can use a *Lambda **Expression*** against **each element of array *A***. (This will essentially act as a **foreach** loop)

Therefore, by **looking up** each value of **one array in the other** with ***XLOOKUP*** inside the ***LAMBDA*** passed to ***SCAN*** we can return an array **equal in length to the one with the lookup values** that contains the **common values** and a **bunch of NA** for whenever the lookup value from one array is not found in the other.

Since we need to find all the common values between the two arrays, we first need to check **which array is largest** to use it as our *lookup array*, to **not miss any elements**.

Finally, in order **to remove all of the unwanted NA values** and end up with our clean ***INTERSECT*** result we use a ***FILTER*** to filter them out.

You can either create a name through the *Name Manager* (eg. ***INTERSECT***) for the ***LAMBDA*** below or just you the *body* of the *LAMDBA* wherever you want.

Note: ***LET*** is being used for *clarity's and sanity's sake* but is **not necessary**.

```
=LAMBDA(array_a, array_b,
    LET(
        scanResult, IF(
            COUNTA(array_a) > COUNTA(array_b),
            SCAN(
                "",
                array_a,
                LAMBDA(accumulator, current, XLOOKUP(current, array_b, array_b))
            ),
            SCAN(
                "",
                array_b,
                LAMBDA(accumulator, current, XLOOKUP(current, array_a, array_a))
            )
        ),
        FILTER(scanResult, NOT(ISNA(scanResult)))
    )
)
```