# Is there any way to do SET(Number of set, Intersection, Union) operations from excel sheet?

Tags: excel, venn-diagram

I have the following excel sheet with Different Phenotypes as header.

[image]

But I need to find out a way to draw venn diagram out of it. For that I need to find out the values like n(1 intersect 2), n(1 intersect 3) ..... so on.
Is there any automated or efficient way to do this?

Comment: From a google search, try [this site](https://www.automateexcel.com/charts/venn-diagram/)

Comment: @PeterT this is a good article , but this differs from my problem. In the document they already have the data like pepsi and cocacola and others. But I need a tool to generate such data from my columns 
as I have 16 columns, so there need to be 16 circles and intersections and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt help the whole way. But had some good references to get the job done.

1. Set function on excel ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186547/how-can-we-perform-common-set-operations-union-intersection-minus-in-ms-exce))
2. Multi set venn diagram(Upto 10 sets). Though it is time consuming and you need to enter manually, but it gets the job done. ([Link](https://www.meta-chart.com/venn#/display))

My output diagram looks just like :
[Venn diagram from the table in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GY5B.png)